# Is there any way that I can send a mail with a file attachment through SoapUI

Tags: soapui

I would like to send a mail through SoapUI with a file attachment so SoapUI has the Send mail step but it doesn't have the facility to attach a file. Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation at 
https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/headers-and-attachments.html

> SoapUI supports the following technologies for working with files and attachments:
>
> - MTOM - a technology for optimized transfer of binary data in SOAP
>     Messages
> - SOAP with Attachments in accordance with Attachments Profile a
>     MIME-based attachment mechanism for the SOAP/HTTP binding
> - Inline files for binary content - soapUI specific functionality for
>     simplifying handling of binary message content
>
> Since the industry, for now, seems to be moving towards MTOM, we currently have no plans for supporting any other attachment technology, for example DIME.
>
> Both MTOM and Inlining of files require internal processing and can be disabled for better performance in the Web Service Request Details Tab. Also, when disabling this feature, soapUI will no longer be required to load the WSDL Definition (either cached or remote) before sending a request.
>
> Attachments in soapUI are managed in the attachment tab at the bottom of the request editor:
>
> [image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11931671)

Comment: Hi Andrew if SoapUI.org drops support for file attachments I would expect the link to become invalid.

Comment: Hi Andrew,I know we can attach file in soapUI but can we send the attachment to someone through mail ?